# I am using Kafka Producer Api to write messages from a file into kafka topic, but the logs of kafka topic is showing empty?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using below Producer API code to write messages into Kafka topic, but its unable to write messages into topic:

```scala
import java.util.Properties
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord}
import scala.io.Source

object KafkaProducerDemo {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val props = new Properties()
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaProducerDemo")
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

        val producer = new KafkaProducer[Nothing, String](props)


        val logMessages = Source.
          fromFile("/opt/gen_logs/logs/access.log").
          getLines.
          toList

        logMessages.foreach(message => {
          val record = new ProducerRecord("retail-multi", message)
          producer.send(record)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: any exception thrown?

Comment: Yes I am getting below exception at Kafka Broker.                                  ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18 at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Api Keys.forId(Api Keys.java:68)

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera  634770 Nov 20  2015 kafka-clients-0.9.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 4960620 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera   48565 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-javadoc.jar

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera  621175 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-sources.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 2802225 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-scaladoc.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera 2049056 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-test.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera     821 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-test.jar.asc
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera     821 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-sources.jar.asc
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera     821 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-scaladoc.jar.asc

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera     821 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0-javadoc.jar.asc
-rw-r--r-- 1 cloudera cloudera     821 Nov 20  2015 kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0.jar.asc

Comment: I have mentioned the versions of jar flies from libs directory

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you mentioned in comments (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18), I'd say you've got a mismatch between your client library version and your broker version. Client lib should be < broker (unless client lib supports dynamic api-version checking).

So double check the broker version you are connecting to, and then double check your client library version. Once they match or are compatible, you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I am new to it can u plz suggest how to check the same. I ahve checked the jar files in libs and it looks good as both server and client jars are of same version.

Comment: ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
 at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ApiKeys.forId(ApiKeys.java:68)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.getRequest(AbstractRequest.java:39)
 at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:79)
 at

Comment: kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$run$11.apply(SocketServer.scala:426)
 at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$run$11.apply(SocketServer.scala:421)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
 at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
 at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
 at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
 at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:421)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Hi i have mentioned library versions and full staketrace also.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927177/kafka-network-processor-error-in-producer-programarrayindexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 0):

Hi I this may be because of some kafka version mismatch. I have re-install kafka and sbt. And it started working fine now.